Getting access to a protected member warning shown by pycharm in descriptor get method
I was trying to play around with Python descriptors and Pycharm IDE seems to be complaining

Am I using descriptors incorrectly? Or is this expected?
Complete code:
class Age:

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value > 200:
            raise ValueError("Age cannot be more than 200")
        instance._age = value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return instance._age


class Employee:
    age = Age()

    def __init__(self):
        self._age = None

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Age: {self.age}"


e = Employee()
e.age = 204
print(e)


This warning is telling you that you violated a convention. You are expected to handle attributes starting with an underscore as "non-public", meaning not to access them from outside the class.
This is not enforced by the interpreter though.
